# Embedding Python in C++ crashes during running-time

Tags: python, c++, multithreading, python-c-api

I've been around this question for way too long. Now I searched [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10625584/embedding-python-in-multithreaded-c-application?lq=1) and it was working for a while but it then crashed at a random place. I think that the problem is a deadlock or something.

So please, someone tell me what I'm doing wrong:

1. I make a global variable:

   ```
   static int gil_init = 0;
   ```
2. At the start of the program I call `Py_Initialize()`. This start function is called multiple times in one session but since `Py_Initialize()` is a non-op if Python is already initialized I don't think there's a problem here.
3. From three functions I make lots of calls into the Python/C API function -`py_embed(...)` (there's only one at a time calling). The next code is present in the `py_embed()` function that is called from each thread:

   ```
   if (!gil_init) {
       gil_init = 1;
       PyEval_InitThreads();
       PyEval_SaveThread();
   }
   state = PyGILState_Ensure();
   // Call Python/C API functions...
   //pValue= PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pArgs2);  Crash is always given here
   PyGILState_Release(state);
   ```

Oh and the crash takes place in one of the functions, but not the first time I call it which is strange. That's why I said its at a random place during running time.

In theory, and based in the reference manual of the [C Api](https://docs.python.org/3.2/c-api/init.html#PyEval_InitThreads) it should be working.. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: I don't call `Py_Finalize()` because of [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7676314/py-initialize-py-finalize-not-working-twice-with-numpy) that I had

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this post](http://www.codevate.com/blog/7-concurrency-with-embedded-python-in-a-multi-threaded-c-application), it helped me with some threading issues I was having. In particular this part:

> *That said, however, I have found that this can lead to intermittent*
>   *deadlocking. It seems that each `PyThreadState` used by*
>   *`PyGILState_Ensure()` is not unique, leading to multiple threads*
>   *attempting to restore the same `PyThreadState`, resulting in a deadlock.*
>   *This is simple enough to overcome by guaranteeing that each thread has*
>   *its own `PyThreadState`. A partial solution is as follows:*

```
 // Once in each thread
 m_state = PyThreadState_New(m_interpreterState);
 PyEval_RestoreThread(m_state);

 // Perform some Python actions here

 // Release Python GIL
 PyEval_SaveThread();
```

Comment: Ty for the comment. Unfortunately that does not work. I set multiple breakpoints and i noticed that when it gets to `m_state = PyThreadState_New(m_interpreterState);` it stops... So the python script isn't even reached

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved it (can't say for sure but until now it hasn't crashed).

The problem was that I was dereferenciating some borrowed references. I noticed this because the reference count of some objects were 2 or 3.