# Calling CPython from multiple threads

Tags: c#, c, cpython, python.net

I'm trying to use pythonnet (C# library) from multiple threads, but it deadlocks.
The following seems to be the procedure for calling CPython from that library:

```
Py_InitializeEx(0); // Initialize CPython
if (PyEval_ThreadsInitialized() == 0)
    PyEval_InitThreads();
// ---------------------------
gs = PyGILState_Ensure();
// Execute some Python code here
PyGILState_Release(gs);
```

However, when running this again from a different thread (not main thread) it deadlocks:

```
gs = PyGILState_Ensure(); // Deadlocks!
// Execute some Python code here
PyGILState_Release(gs);
```

What is the proper way to call CPython from multiple threads?

The following question:

[Embedding python in multithreaded C application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10625584/embedding-python-in-multithreaded-c-application)

seems to be related, but I am non the wiser in what the "correct" approach is?

Comment: The GIL is a *Global* interpreter lock. You cannot have two threads executing python code at the same time.

Comment: @Botje I know that, but as I understand it, the GIL is a lock -- a mutex -- which goal is to prevent that from happening. It should block, but not deadlock.

Comment: How did you diagnose this as a deadlock? That involves two threads holding locks waiting for each other's locks to be unlocked.